# Создание менеджера движения объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть игра в которой каждый уровень - новая сцена.
Есть персонаж которым управляет игрок,перед ним объекты.Если персонаж прикасается к ним , то он умирает.Если же он смог пройти их то его перекидывает на след. уровень.
В принципе, сами объекты двигаются при лёгких алгоритмах и ничего сложно в их движении нету.Разница в том , что у каждого разный код небольших размеров.
Думаю,здесь возможно из них сделать префабы и потом от этого и двигаться дальше.
Объектов на одной сцене не много(4-16). 
Проблема заключается в том чтобы создать единый менеджер движения объектов и нужен ли он вообще?
Пока есть только куча отдельных скриптов для каждого типа объектов , а их не так уж и мало.

Один из вариантов:

Запихнуть весь код из десятков скриптов в один скрипт, потом создать публичную переменную типа `int`  и проверять её

```
 if (int i == 0)
{
  Логика движения объекта первого типа;
}
 if (int i == 1)
{
  Логика движения объекта второго типа;
}
 if (int i == 2)
{
  Логика движения объекта третьего типа;
}
```

И просто навешать один скрипт на все объекты,а не держать у себя десяток скриптов по отдельности.

Но,есть проблема:

-Куча публичных переменных , которые будут на каждом объекте(мне нужно 2-4 для работы с определенным типом объекта).

Также я бы хотел услышать другие идеи по этому вопросу

Comment: а точно нужно иметь один большой менеджер? кажется, что идея компонентов, как раз таки разбивать такие сущности

Comment: Возможно,вы правы.

Comment: Логика движения так сильно различается, что пришлось создавать много компонентов? Это полёг, бег, телепортация? Или просто разные скорости движения?) если первый вариант - то в этом смысл правильной архитектуры) так гораздо проще работать с кодом и следить за тем, чтобы один не вмешивался в другой. Если у них есть некоторая часть общей логики - используйте наследование.

Comment: Думаю,движение у них различается сильно.

Comment: @ThisMan не обязательно всё делать через компоненты. И большой менеджер вполне можно (но не "нужно") иметь. Так например в книге Алана Торна "Искусство создания сценариев в Unity" создается `EventManager` для управления событиями и есть советы по глобальным вещам делать менеджеры. Почему нет? Также тут: https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/ делается общий `Update` для 10000 объектов - что дает производительность и некие плюшки. Но всё, конечно, относительно и зависит от. Поэтому в данном случае может и не менджер нужен, а применение паттерна и остальные танцы уже от него

Comment: @Veudd тут можно многое наговорить. Тут надо наверное больше информации. Что за объекты и почему у вас их очень и очень много. Почему нельзя выделить объекты в префабы с соответствующими скриптами? Ведь префабами проще оперировать в плане не нужно навешивать на 1000 объектов 1000 скриптов и типов объектов в виде префаба будет конечно меньше.. Нужно знать еще что будущие объекты будут делать, на сколько различна логика движения и пр.

Comment: Если в игре есть "много" объектов и "много" скриптов поведения, требующих своего обособленно класса, то вы делаете что-то не так. А в целом для огромного кол-ва объектов с одинаковым поведением по группам можно использовать архитектуру Data Oriented Programming.